# How can i pass value from one angular module another Module?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Iam New To Angular Concept Iam trying to pass an Value  from one  Module to another. 
I Used Meanjs Generator added few more modules for every Module as per requirement .

Example :-
Restaurant Controller From Restaurant Module :-

```
 angular.module('restaurants').controller('RestaurantController', ['$scope','$http','$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication','$rootScope'
    function($scope,$http, $stateParams, $location, Authentication,$rootScope) { 

        $scope.create = function() {
            // Create new Restaurant object

           var resObj = {
                displayName: this.displayName,

            var restaurant = new Restaurants(resObj);

            // Redirect after save
            restaurant.$save(function(response) {
                $location.path('restaurants/'+ restaurant._id);
             **Need to Pass restaurant._id to the Menusconttoller**
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        }; 

]);
```

**I need to Pass Restaurant Id to the Menu Controller Below Is that Possible ?**

```
angular.module('menus').controller('MenusController1', ['$scope','$http', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication'
     function($scope,$http, $stateParams, $location,Authentication) {


       // Create new Menu
        $scope.create = function () {
            $scope.isCreateloading=true;
            var menusObj= {
                'displayName' : this.displayName
                restaurantId  : this.restaurantId // **where i need to recieve the Id which is pased from Restaurant Controller**            
          };


    here i need to get the Id from Restaurant Module 
            $scope.menuForm=menusObj;
                var  menu = new Menus1(menusObj);

                // Redirect after save
                menu.$save(function (response) {
                    $location.path('menus/'+menu._id);

                }, function (errorResponse) {
                    $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
                });
        };
```

]);

i did $rootscope Broadcasting ,$scope.emit etc but those all examples having more controllers in  same module. Which is not suited to My Scenario.

Please Suggest:-

** How can i pass  id from One Module to Another Module ?** 
**Thanks For helping Novice !!**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can do that this way:**

```
//this is one module
var myUtilModule = angular.module("myUtilModule", []);

// this is value to be shared among modules, it can be any value
myUtilModule.value  ("myValue"  , "12345");

//this is another module
var myOtherModule = angular.module("myOtherModule", ['myUtilModule']);

myOtherModule.controller("MyController", function($scope, myValue) {
      // myValue of first module is available here
}
```

Here is tutorial [AngularJS Modularization & Dependency Injection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/dependency-injection.html)

Happy Helping!